# How to quickly get coverage of multiple services at once using pgrouting driving distance

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I'm trying to get some useful information out of openstreetmap data to choose where to rent an apartment in my city.
I used osm2pgrouting and osm2pgsql to get OSM data into my postgis database.
So far I've managed to create a view (`nearest_poi`) with the id of the nearest neighbor of my POIs (some type of shops, bus stations and parks from OSM points and polygons), along with the category of the poi and the maximum distance I would like to be from that category (`near_vertex_id, category, distance`).

To be able to get the coverage *in a single view* I used pgr_drivingdistance from all the points of `nearest_poi` using the absolute maximum distance (`max_distance` is a table that stores the couple `category-distance`) and then I get rid of the points with distance greater than the maximum distance for that category:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW coverage_pts AS
SELECT id, the_geom, min(distance) as distance, category, max_distance
FROM (
  SELECT v.id, v.the_geom, di.agg_cost as distance, n.category, n.distance as max_distance
  FROM pgr_drivingdistance(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length_m as cost FROM ways',
    array(SELECT DISTINCT near_vertex FROM nearest_poi),
    (SELECT max(distance) FROM max_distances),
    false, false
  ) as di
  JOIN ways_vertices_pgr v ON di.node = v.id
  JOIN nearest_poi n ON di.from_v = n.near_vertex
  WHERE di.agg_cost<=n.distance
) coverage
GROUP by id, the_geom, category, max_distance
```

Finally I get the points covered by all the services using:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT  id, the_geom, count(category) AS tot_services
  FROM  coverage_pts
  GROUP by id, the_geom
) AS hottest_point
WHERE tot_services = 20 --I have 20 categories
```

All is working fine except the last query takes about 10 seconds for 427 POIs on my 2008 MacBook Pro. When I try to visualize the points in QGIS, the refresh time when panning/zooming is very high.

Is there something I can do to speed up the operations? I also would like to keep it as "compact" as possible (avoid to break data into multiple views by category, the only alternative I thought of).

Comment: double check your indexes and your postgres server config...  see the links in this post:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192593/postgis-how-can-i-improve-the-response-time-for-getting-the-routed-distance-bet